# How to make iTerm autocomplete a partial command when pressing the 'up' arrow key?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I currently have iTerm version 3.4.12.

In my old work computer I had a different version that would autocomplete a partial command based on the previous commands I had typed when pressing the up key, for example if at some point I ran:

`cd Desktop`

And then I went back to the folder where I ran it and tried typing

`cd De`

Followed by pressing the up key it would autocomplete to `cd Desktop`

Now I'm on a different computer and pressing the up key simply goes through the history of commands I've ran regardless of the folder I'm in or what I've typed, how can I make it so it autocompletes paritially based on my history instead?

Comment: Hi, this question is not really about programming so it belongs to SuperUser rather than here. Also it is not related to iTerm itself but shell you run in it (bash, zsh, fish…) as that is what runs commands and does autocompletion.

Answer (score 5):

## Brief

Hi, actually this is what are you looking for [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/).
It's a really complete framework for `zsh` that brings a lot of functionality and the capability to add external plugins.

## Installation

1. Execute the following in your terminal

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

2. it should updated your `~/.zshrc` file with a bunch of stuff including some default useful plugin, you can restart your terminal or resource the configuration file just typing

```
$ zsh
```

## Plugins

You can find other external plugin like `zsh-autosuggestions`, this actually brings you an `autocomplete` feature during the typing phase

[image: like this]

To Install this as other plugin you can follow this

1. Open your .zshrc configuration file inside your terminal

```
$ vi ~/.zshrc
```

#### Note

if vi does not work try to use `nano` or `vim` instead, if you don't have even nano you can just open the file via GUI using any text editor

2. Inside the configuration file, find the `plugin` section, and inside the round brackets add `zsh-autosuggestions`

   ```
    # Which plugins would you like to load?
    # Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
    # Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
    # Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
    # Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
    plugins=(
    git
    bundler
    dotenv
    osx
    rake
    zsh-autosuggestions
    last-working-dir
    web-search
    brew
    extract
    history
    sudo
    yarn
    )
   ```
3. Restart your terminal and you should be done! For more information you can find the github repo of [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh)